# MySQL: Insert top N rows from each group into a table. Assume millions of groups

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Doing this for one group is simple:

```
INSERT INTO top_dancers_by_group
    SELECT group_id, dancer_id
    FROM dancers
    WHERE group_id = 1
    ORDER BY how_good_they_do_a_half_turn DESC
    LIMIT 1000
```

Now let's assume there's a `groups` table which contains thousands of group IDs. How do I perform this insert for every group ID in pure MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry what `group by`?

Comment: good question. i must be smokin something

Comment: The group by is effectively `group_id` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a stored procedure:

```sql
delimiter $$
create procedure insert_top_dancers_by_group()
begin
    declare gId int;
    declare done tinyint default 0;
    declare curGroup cursor for
        select distinct group_id from dancers;
    declare continue handler for not found
        set done = 1;

    open curGroup;
    group_insert: while done=0 do
        fetch curGroup into gId;
        if done = 0 then
            -- If you want to remove the previous stored dancers for this group:
            delete from top_dancers_by_group where group_id = gId;
            -- Insert the top dancers for this group:
            insert into top_dancers_by_group
                select group_id, dancer_id
                from dancers
                where group_id = gId
                order by how_good_they_do_a_half_turn DESC
                limit 1000;
        end if;
    end while;
    close curGroup;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Hope this helps.

---

You can also use a parameter in this procedure to define how many rows are inserted:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure insert_top_n_dancers_by_group(n int)
begin
    declare gId int;
    declare done tinyint default 0;
    declare curGroup cursor for
        select distinct group_id from dancers;
    declare continue handler for not found
        set done = 1;

    open curGroup;
    group_insert: while done=0 do
        fetch curGroup into gId;
        if done = 0 then
            -- If you want to remove the previous stored dancers for this group:
            delete from top_dancers_by_group where group_id = gId;
            -- Insert the top dancers for this group:
            insert into top_dancers_by_group
                select group_id, dancer_id
                from dancers
                where group_id = gId
                order by how_good_they_do_a_half_turn DESC
                limit n;
        end if;
    end while;
    close curGroup;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Once you've created the procedure(s), you can call them like this:

```
call insert_top_dancers_by_group();
```

Comment: Bravo, thank you. A lot of new MySQL features here for me, but I think I understand everything that's going on. Assuming the group ID is a string, would I `declare gId varchar(32)` or something similar? Also, is there no practical inline way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Dan I'm glad this was useful to you. Of course, `gId` must be of the same type of the `group_id` field in your table. And... I think this is the cheapest way to do it, specially if you are dealing with a big table. (If it is useful, accept it ;-) )

Comment: This ended up working really well. From a performance standpoint, I modified it in the following way: the server manages two instances of the top_dancers_by_group table (_1 and _2, so one can be read from while the other is being updated). The procedure drops the existing table, creates a new one without indexes, inserts all of the rows, and finally adds the indexes. Once the process is complete, the server updates its configuration to mark the new table as the one to read from.